# my app stays in "draft" mode (play store)

Tags: android

In my google developer console, all the app info is given but the publish mode is still "draft mode ".It show
<<
Why can't I publish?

You need to complete the points below before you can publish your application.

You need to acknowledge that this application meets the Content Guidelines.

> >

I cant see anywhere to click and accept some rules there! Anywhere in the console.Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.I miss this one is finally i found it.
Go to your the Developer Console. Click on your app's name. This will bring up the screen where you entered the data for your store listing. On the left side of the screen are a number of menu items. Click on the one for Pricing and Distribution. Scroll to the bottom of the page that comes up and there you will find the place to acknowledge that the app meets Content Guidelines and to acknowledge that it complies with US Export Laws. 
Read the info for each before clicking them to ensure your app really does comply.

Comment: Correct me If I'm wrong go to Payment Profile > manage settings > United States tax info

Answer (score 2):

(For other people) sometimes reason why it stays in the draft mode  is just applying the rating to the application is forgotten. After you fill the questionnaire dont forget to apply rating to the app.

Comment: this is not clear where is this located

Comment: Left hand menu "Policy -> App Content"

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was a missing translation for descriptions. You really need to be careful on that because it can't be found for current UI.